# Cannot read property 'displayImage' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, pug, formidable

I am developing a web app with node js. When trying to upload a picture and save in the file system of the app I get the error :

```
Cannot read property 'displayImage' of undefined
```

My code for the post of the image is the following:

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile( req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
    var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/uploadedFileName";
    fs.rename(newPath, 'filename', function (err) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});
```

And in the view

```
form(action="upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input(type="file", name="displayImage")
    input(type='submit')
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

PS: I also have read some tutorials in where formidable module is used. It is recommended to use it or as I have done is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of express are you using ? In express 4.0 for multipart bodies you should use an alternatives.

For example, you can implement upload files using [multer npm module](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

```
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(multer({dest: './uploads/'}));

//app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
//    console.log(req.files);
//});
```